# how to dynamically add REQUIRED attribute to textarea tag using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I tried adding `REQUIRED` attribute using `.attr("required","true");` but its not making text area compulsory. Do not want to make all `textarea`, compulsory, hence trying to do it dynamically.

Comment: Can you confirm which browsers you are testing with?
Also can you provide the <DOCTYPE> header from your page?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
$('#myTextarea').prop('required',true);
```

Comment: I think its issue with my page, i have tag "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />" which makes page load in standard mode..but still i get error "Object #<Object> has no method 'prop' "..however, if i put same code in single HTML page..it works fine...thanks though

Comment: Are you loading jquery at least? If yes, which version?

Comment: :)..yes sir..Jquery 1.7.2 and other Jquery animations and codes are working fine. Just some methods are missing , not sure why, e.g nextUntil , prop...these methods do not work..in IE and Chrome

Comment: Is it a customized (rebuild) jquery version you are using? Test from a CDN: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>