# jQuery to Validate an Input Text Control based on Radio Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I validate that the input text corresponding to the radio option is checked?

[image: screen capture]

For example, using the image above:

- If Contact 1's **E-Mail radio option** is selected, Contact 1's **E-Mail text field** cannot be blank, but Contact 1's Phone and US Mail text fields are still permitted.
- If Contact 2's **US Mail radio option** is selected, Contact 2's **US Mail text field** cannot be blank, but Contact 2's Phone and E-Mail text fields are still permitted.

I have built the form above using the HTML below, but you can play with my Fiddle here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jp2code/zYkLF).

**BEGIN UPDATE:** I have a newer fiddle with better code here:

[fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/jp2code/zYkLF/3/)

It has more instructions in the HTML and a closer attempt at my jQuery. For some reason, though, it still does not seem to be doing anything.

**END UPDATE**

I have tried naming the fields so that my jQuery can parse them, but that does not mean there is not a better way.

```
<body>
  <form name="jp2code" action="#" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Contact 1</legend>
        <span>
            <input type="radio" id="group1_PhoneRadio" name="group1"/>
            <label for="group1_PhoneText">Phone:</label>
            <input type="text" id="group1_PhoneText" name="group1_PhoneText"/>
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" id="group1_EMailRadio" name="group1"/>
            <label for="group1_EMailText">E-Mail:</label>
            <input type="text" id="group1_EMailText" name="group1_EMailText"/>
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" id="group1_USMailRadio" name="group1"/>
            <label for="group1_USMailText">US Mail:</label>
            <input type="text" id="group1_USMailText" name="group1_USMailText"/>
        </span>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Contact 2</legend>
        <span>
            <input type="radio" id="group2_PhoneRadio" name="group2"/>
            <label for="group2_PhoneText">Phone:</label>
            <input type="text" id="group2_PhoneText" name="group2_PhoneText"/>
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" id="group2_EMailRadio" name="group2"/>
            <label for="group2_EMailText">E-Mail:</label>
            <input type="text" id="group2_EMailText" name="group2_EMaiText"/>
            <br/>                
            <input type="radio" id="group2_USMailRadio" name="group2"/>
            <label for="group2_USMailText">US Mail:</label>
            <input type="text" id="group2_USMailText" name="group2_USMailText"/>
        </span>
    </fieldset>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

### What is the best way to write the jQuery?

I am new to jQuery, but I attempted my hand at it based on some [Show/hide examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2777139/153923).

What I created below does not work, but hopefully indicates what I am trying to accomplish.

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type='radio']").change(function() { // when a radio button in the group changes
        var id = $(this).id;
        var index = id.indexOf('group');
        if (index == 0) { // is there a better way to do this?
          var groupN_Len = 7; // Length of 'groupN_'
          var radio_Len = 5; // Length of 'radio'
          var preStr = id.substring(0, groupN_Len);
          $"input[name*='preStr']".validate = null; // clear validation for all text inputs in the group
          var postStr = id.substring(groupN_Len + 1, id.Length() + 1 - radio_Len); // extract Phone, EMail, or USMail
          $(preStr+postStr+'Text').validate({ rules: { name: { required: true } } });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You can use jQuery Validate.

Comment: There is some `validate` in my jQuery, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Please check this fiddle to see if this was what you are looking for. http://jsfiddle.net/zYkLF/1/

Comment: +1 tilda. After the `.each(function()`, I need to somehow set all **validate rule** for all inputs in the same group to `required: false` before setting the **validate rule** for `$("input[name^="+checkboxId+"]")` to `required: true`. But, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you want. Please explain it with an example.

Comment: Newer code http://jsfiddle.net/jp2code/zYkLF/3/

Comment: Check out dependency expressions in jQuery Validate.  You can write `required:'#group2_USMailRadio:checked'` as a rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, whatever radio button is selected in the Contact Group's **Contact Preferences**, that corresponding text field is required.

Here is where I am so far on my jQuery checking:

**EDIT:**

1. Modified with [tilda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2828318/tilda)'s important detail about adding '.' to the class name.
2. Added Required Attribute: [how to dynamically add REQUIRED attribute to textarea tag using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17381043/153923)
3. Removed Required Attribute: [jquery removing html5 required attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13951336/153923)

Final code works and looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    debug: true,
    success: "valid"
  });
  $("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
    $('.'+$(this).attr('name')).each(function(index) {
      $(this).removeAttr('required');
    });
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('.'+$(this).attr('id')).each(function(index) {
        $(this).prop('required',true);
      });
    }
  });
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    $(this).validate();
  });
});
```

Back to the HTML of the document: I did a lot of subtle editing to the text by creating specific **id**s and **name**s for the radio buttons that matched up with the **class** names for the text controls.

Here is that end result:

```
<body>
  <form name="jp2code" action="#" method="POST">
    <div>For each field below, provide the Phone Number, E-Mail Address, and Street Address. <b>Indicate the preferred contact method using the radio button.</b></div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Contact 1</legend>
        <span>
            <input type="radio" id="group1_Phone" name="group1"/>
            <label for="group1_Phone">Phone:</label>
            <input type="text" name="group1_PhoneText" class="group1 group1_Phone" />
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" id="group1_EMail" name="group1"/>
            <label for="group1_EMail">E-Mail:</label>
            <input type="text" name="group1_EMailText" class="group1 group1_EMail" />
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" id="group1_USMail" name="group1"/>
            <label for="group1_USMail">US Mail:</label>
            <input type="text" name="group1_USMailText" class="group1 group1_USMail" />
        </span>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Contact 2</legend>
        <span>
            <input type="radio" id="group2_Phone" name="group2"/>
            <label for="group2_Phone">Phone:</label>
            <input type="text" name="group2_PhoneText" class="group2 group2_Phone" />
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" id="group2_EMail" name="group2"/>
            <label for="group2_EMail">E-Mail:</label>
            <input type="text" name="group2_EMailText" class="group2 group2_EMail" />
            <br/>                
            <input type="radio" id="group2_USMail" name="group2"/>
            <label for="group2_USMail">US Mail:</label>
            <input type="text" name="group2_USMailText" class="group2 group2_USMail" />
        </span>
    </fieldset>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit"/>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Let me explain what is going on in the jQuery, using the HTML above:

- When a radio button's checked state changes, each control with a *class name* that matches the *radio button's name* attribute has the **required** property removed.
- If a radio button is checked (i.e. `checked=true`), then each control with a *class name* that matches the *radio button's id* attribute has the **required** property added.
- Finally, the validator seems to have to be run on a single form control (not on individual text controls like I was doing).

Here is the sample Fiddle that I ended with: [Fiddle v8](http://jsfiddle.net/jp2code/zYkLF/8/)

At [tilda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2828318/tilda): You didn't say much, but what you did say helped a lot!

[image: screen capture]

Comment: Call `$.validate` once on `$(document).ready`, not all the time.  I suggest viewing the [examples](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/) carefully.

Comment: Correction: `var radName='group1'; $('.' + radName).validate...`

Comment: The code works now. I thought jQuery was supposed to be easy?

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that the radiobutton is checked for each field, add attribute `required=""` in one of the radiobuttons for each fieldset.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zYkLF/6/)